# Trying to extract json data, geting expected string or buffer

Tags: python, json, buffer, utorrent

So I'm experimenting with json abit and this is the code I've got this far,

```
import json
from utorrent.client import UTorrentClient

uTorrent = UTorrentClient("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx")

data = uTorrent.list()

torrents = json.loads(data)["torrents"]

for torrent in torrents:
    print item[0] # hash
    print item[2] # name
    print item[21] # status
    print item[26] # folder
```

The typical json output can be viewed [here](http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/webapi#devs6). But im getting an "expected string or buffer" error. Anyone with any pointers?

The point with above code is to print out each hash/name.. for each torrent found in the list provided by uTorrent

Comment: what is `type(data)`? utorrent might have already decoded json text into corresponding Python objects for you.

Comment: you could ask me if my answer is not suitable for you)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using *load* instead of *loads*? I was having the same problem and I realized there's a difference.